# How to log my Remote Desktop / Terminal Services activity on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, logging, citrix

I am working remotely (Windows 7), and connecting to my Windows XP machine at the office via Remote Desktop via Citrix. Is there a simple way to log my activity other than just the logon and logoff? If my boss ever questions my work, I'd like a simple way to show that my machine was connected to and very active since I get much more done from home without all the distractions of an office! Thanks.

Comment: Do you log thru a VPN or Firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a piece of software such as [**RescueTime**](http://www.rescuetime.com/) will do the trick (installed on your XP computer in the office).

If you have pretty graphs of computer usage to back up your argument, I doubt your boss will be able to argue back.

> RescueTime sits in the background and
>   measures which application, web site
>   or (optionally) document is actively
>   being used.

[image]

Another option is **[Wakoopa](http://www.wakoopa.com/)** which also has pretty graphs.

> How productive are you?
>   Know what you use and for how long.